# Multiple Selectors in Selenium Test

Tags: css, selenium, testng, selenide

I want to test a page with responsive layout.
Some elements (like the menu) will be different depending on resolution.

how can I target them to run with the same test classes?

i'm thinking about `How.CSS, using = "a.normal-link, a#responsive-link"`

is this a good idea? is there a *better* way?

and is it possible to "inject" some kind of workaround-logic for specific occasions? (for example: if the normal login-button is not visible, **try to open the responsive menu**, then click the **other** (responsive) login-link)
I was just thinking about a try-catch block, but that feels wrong for an alternative route.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As, you need to check whether an element is visible or not, it is better to use `if/else` blocks, to validate the same. Sample piece of code is given below:

```
if(driver.findElement(<Your element>).isDisplayed()) {
     // Perform your operations
} else {
     // Open the button from menu item
}
```

Hope this helps.